# Array element automatically set to undef won't change when aliased?

Tags: perl

Relating to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18090182/557306)  question, what's the difference between  a manually set
to `undef` list element and one that was  set by Perl when growing the size of
that  list by  assigning to  a bigger  index than  the list  size, when  being
aliased? For example, considering this code:

```
@a = (undef, 0);
@b = ();
$b[1] = 0;

print Dumper(@a), "\n", Dumper(@b);
```

It prints (as expected, I think):

```
$VAR1 = undef;
$VAR2 = 0;

$VAR1 = undef;
$VAR2 = 0;
```

So, aren't the arrays the same? Apparently not:

```
sub change { $_[0] = 1 }
change(@a); change(@b);
print Dumper(@a), "\n", Dumper(@b);
```

Which prints:

```
$VAR1 = 1;
$VAR2 = 0;

$VAR1 = undef;
$VAR2 = 0;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You found a fascinating edge case.

When you explicitly set an element, it first springs into existence. If an array is extended so that multiple indices fall into range of this array, no scalars are implicitly initialized at these positions. Example:

```
my @array;
$array[2] = undef; # this extends the array
# now elements 0–2 report as `undef`, but only #2 was initalized
```

When we ask whether these elements exist, we get:

```
say "index $_ ", exists $array[$_] ? "exists" : "doesn't exist" for 0 .. 4;
```

Output:

```
index 0 doesn't exist
index 1 doesn't exist
index 2 exists
index 3 doesn't exist
index 4 doesn't exist
```

This optimization saves you from allocating unused scalars at these positions; the array access code just returns an `undef` when there isn't anything there stating otherwise.

Now this squares badly with function calls. When a subroutine is called, a flat list of scalars is put on the stack, which is then accessible as `@_`. No copying takes place here, so this is call by alias. Now when the `$_[0]` element is accessed in your sub, there is no scalar here, so it creates a new one in `@_`:

```
sub crazy {
  say 1*exists $_[0];
  $_[0] = 1;
  say 1*exists $_[0];
}

my @array; $array[2] = 0;
crazy @array;

say 1*exists $array[0];
```

Output:

```
0
1
0
```

Internally, a scalar is a pointer to an `SV` struct. These pointers are copied onto the stack, so this makes actual modification of the original `@array` impossible.

Answer (score 6):

One difference is that `exists $a[0]` is true and `exists $b[0]` is false.